# how to use sbt 1.5.3 with scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

Just made sure that my scala is 2.13.6 and my sbt is 1.5.3 (I use sdkman).
Why? Because I'm switching to Scala 3 and follow the [instructions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/tutorial-sbt.html).

Can't compile:

`The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.13:1.2.1:compile could not be retrieved.`

Is there a solution to this problem?

build.properties:

```
sbt.version=1.2.1
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Please provide the full error message and your `build.properties` content + which command are you running (`sbt compile` I assume?)

Answer (score -1):

This was fixed when I replaced `sbt.version` in `build.properties`: with `sbt.version=1.5.3` it worked perfectly.